# How to infer a type in a base class dependant on the inheriting class at runtime without if statements?

Tags: c#

I have this little OO problem..

```
abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass
{    
   MyHelperClassBase myHelperBaseClass;

   protected method foo()
   {
       //QUESTION....... :  when I am here I want to do this...

       myHelperBaseClass = new MyHelperSubClass(); 

       //OR...

       myHelperBaseClass = new MyOtherHelperSubClass();

       //HOWEVER ITS COMPLETELY CONDITIONAL ON THE BASE CLASS
       //HOW DO I MAKE SURE THE CORRECT TYPE IS INSTANTIATED DEPENDANT ON
       //THE BASE CLASS WITHOUT USING AN 'if' STATEMENT?
   }    
}

class MySubClass : MyAbstractClass {}    
class MyOtherSubClass : MyAbstractClass {}    
/////////////

abstract class MyHelperClassBase {}    

class MyHelperSubClass : MyHelperClassBase, IMyHelper {}    
class MyOtherHelperSubClass : MyHelperClassBase, IMyHelper {}
```

I want to be able to have a the type basically passed up but cant think of a slick way to do this. Should I just stuck an abstract property on the base class?

Comment: What are actually trying to accomplish? It's pretty likely an `abstract` method/property is called for.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's completely conditional on the base class"? In what way? The base class is fixed. Do you mean it's conditional on which *subclass* is being instantiated? If so, it sounds like you need an abstract method in the base class, implemented by each subclass. It's basically unclear what you're trying to do at the moment though...

Comment: Its not depending on it I just needs to instantiate the correct type depending on what is in an inheriting class. I could just use an if sattement but I dont want to .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older OO way of solving this (without generics) involves a virtual or abstract method on the base that the derived classes must implement. This is pretty common in parallel hierarchies like your example:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass{

    MyHelperClassBase myHelper;

    protected void foo() {
        myHelper = createHelper();
    }

    protected abstract MyHelperClassBase createHelper();
}

class MySubClass : MyAbstractClass{
    protected override MyHelperClassBase createHelper(){
        return new MyHelperSubClass();
    }
}

class MyOtherSubClass : MyAbstractClass{
    protected override MyHelperClassBase createHelper(){
        return new MyOtherHelperSubClass();
    }
}
```

Generics come in very handy, but sometimes it's good to know this way, too.

Comment: Hi, yeah cheers this is what I was looking for I dont really get the generics one but Ill have a go at implementing it later If I get the chance...

Answer (score 3):

Your goals are somewhat unclear.  If the goal is to associate a helper class with a specific implementation of the class, there are a couple of options.

You can use generics:

```
abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass<T> where T : MyHelperClassBase, new()
{
     T myHelper;

     protected void Foo()
     {
         myHelper = new T(); // This will be the appropriate subclass
     }
}

// Derived classes become ...
class MySubClass : MyAbstractClass<MyHelperSubClass>
{
}

// Derived classes become ...
class MyOtherSubClass : MyAbstractClass<MyOtherHelperSubClass>
{
}
```

Alternatively, you could have an abstract property in the base class, and the subclasses could implement it:

```
abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass<T> where T : MyHelperClassBase, new()
{
     MyHelperClassBase myHelper;

     abstract protected Func<MyHelperClassBase> MyHelperClassBaseFactory { get; }

     protected void Foo()
     {
         // Construct as needed...
         myHelper = MyHelperClassBaseFactory();
     }

}

// Derived classes implement...
class MySubClass : MyAbstractClass
{
     protected override Func<MyHelperClassBase> MyHelperClassBaseFactory 
     { 
         get { return () => new MyHelperSubClass(); }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, How do I make the generic class also inherit from another class?

Comment: @Pete2k: Just like you would with a non-generic one, ie:  `class MyGenericClass<T> : MyBaseClass where T : MyConstraint` - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: Thanks Reed, been trying to figure out Generics for ages think the penny finally dropped. I implemented your solution over the top of my one so just to see if it works in the morning ! :-)

Comment: @Pete2k Don't give up - generics are worth learning.  They will take your programming to another level, as there is SO much you can do with so much less code by using them.